# Woocommerce get selected shipping zone id for the current user

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

How can I get the selected shipping zone ID based on the current user in WooCommerce?

I tried the code below, but I didn't get the **zoneID** from the cart page:

```
$bh_packages =  $cart->get_shipping_packages();
$shipping_zone = wc_get_shipping_zone( $bh_packages );
$zone = $shipping_zone->get_zone_name();  
var_dump($zone);
```

Comment: Any chance to get some feed back on the answer please (thank you).

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that `WC_Cart` `get_shipping_packages()` method gives an **array** of shipping packages and the function `wc_get_shipping_zone( $package )` expect to have as argument a unique package.

So you need to get only one package, using for example php `reset()` function like:

```
// Get cart shipping packages
$shipping_packages =  WC()->cart->get_shipping_packages();

// Get the WC_Shipping_Zones instance object for the first package
$shipping_zone = wc_get_shipping_zone( reset( $shipping_packages ) );

$zone_id   = $shipping_zone->get_id(); // Get the zone ID
$zone_name = $shipping_zone->get_zone_name(); // Get the zone name

// Testing output
echo '<p>Zone id: ' . $zone_id . ' | Zone name: ' . $zone_name . '</p>';
```

Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I kept getting "Locations not covered by your other zones", turns out I just needed to pass one array key.